# ¿Por qué usar private y no final?

Tags: java, método

Me esta surgiendo una duda:

¿Por qué usar el modificador de acceso **private** y no **final**?

Porqué al añadir **private** nos aseguramos de que ese dato no se va a poder modificar ni acceder a él, pero si ponemos **final** nos aseguramos que el dato no se modificará y nos ahorramos crear un método getter para acceder a este.

Comment: La premisa que tienes para `Private` es incorrecta. No implica que no podamos modificar el **atributo**, sólo restringe la posibilidad de hacerlo.

Comment: Los modificadores de acceso como tal solo son: public, private y protected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el private es un tipo de modificador de acceso, al igual que public, protected o el por defecto (sin modificador). Eso significa que no es que se pueda o no se pueda cambiar una variable, sino que dependiendo del lugar donde se intenta acceder, se pueda acceder a él o no.

final es para convertir una variable en constante. Independientemente de desde donde se acceda, una constante podrá ser leida, pero no cambiada. (Si inicializada, dada un valor, no cambiado ese valor una vez asignado)

Las variables de clase deberían de estar todas encapsuladas. Yo siempre pongo el mismo ejemplo: Cuando un usuario utiliza el objeto linterna, no accede a los cables para unir 2 cables y cerrar el circuito que hace lucir la bombilla. Sino que utiliza el método interruptor. Este método ya se encarga él internamente de acceder a los cables y cerrar el circuito que hace lucir la bombilla, pero el usuario sólo tiene acceso al interruptor.

Las constantes sin embargo pueden venir muy bien tenerlas más abiertas, no en private. Pues pueden tener valores que se necesiten para varias clases.

Ejemplo de constante: En la interfaz principal de un programa con diversos JFrame tenemos definido un color de fondo que será parte del aspecto de nuestro programa, por ejemplo, el color miRojo con un código especial RGB. Pues puede ser perfectamente lógico ponerlo como final para que no se pueda cambiar, como static para que no dependa del objeto sino de la clase, y public para que sea desde donde sea que se intente acceder a él se pueda usar. Pues nuestro programa puede tener múltiples paquetes cada uno encargado de lo que fuere, con su interfaz, y todas esas clases podrán tener elementos que necesiten de ese color.

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de la clase, puedes acceder y modificar los atributos aún privados.
Supongo que es por seguridad o dejar claro que esa variable NO puede cambiar.
(Sobretodo en proyectos grandes en equipo dónde a las clases se le añade métodos cada cierto tiempo). Varios programadores puede modificar el código .

Ademas puedes hacer una constante con un modificador -static final- (No es privado pero usa el final), por lo que en este caso necesitas que exista el modificador final. 
Por ejemplo `Math.PI`

En conclusión, es muy similar al modificador `public`, que es el que está por defecto en la mayoría de los caso. Pudiendo ser opcional o escribirlo para dejarlo explicito

Answer (score 1):

Private y final son 2 cosas diferentes.

Private es un modificador de acceso es para hacer una variable privada y solo podrá ser utilizada en la clase en la que es definida, no se podrá acceder a ella desde otras clases o paquetes.

Answer (score 1):

Los modificadores de acceso son:

- public
- private
- protected

Si tu defines una propiedad o método como `private` entonces solo podrá ser manipulada en el *contexto de la clase que la definió*

Por otro lado para el caso de la palabra reservada *final* :

- Si se la declaras a una clase entonces las demás clases no podrán heredar de ella; es decir:

---

```
final class Algo
{

}


class Otra extends Algo
{

}
```

Nos daría error pues la clase no puede heredar

Por otro lado si defines como *final* a los métodos de una clase entonces si se podrá hacer herencia... pero no podrás modificar o anular (override) el comportamiento que ya tienen previamente definidos.